# How to get a substring of char out of a string of ints

Tags: java, string, char, int, substring

I want to return the substring of alpha characters between two sets of ints of any length.

For example, with the strings below, I would like to return the substring "JKL":

```
123JKL1234
456545645456JKL13
```

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: Indicate what you've tried, what platform you're using and I'll happily reverse my downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can also just replace all numerals in the string to an empty char:

```
String test = "456545645456JKL13";
String str = test.replaceAll("\\d+",""); // str == "JKL"
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) :

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+([a-zA-Z]+)\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("123test4567");
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // prints "test"
```